# Getting results from subtasks in a group

Tags: python, celery

I'm new to Celery and some of its concepts are still not very clear to me. I'm trying to solve [another problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206618/using-group-result-in-a-celery-chain), and so far got a smaller and runnable piece of code, which does a thing similar to what I'm trying to achieve. Now I don't understand whether it is possible to get the ultimate result from executing the below chain, which should be an array like:

`["[MARY]", "[HAD]", "[A]", "[LITTLE]", "[LAMB]"]` (in whatever order)?

Thanks

```
import celery
from celery import subtask

app = celery.Celery('celtest', backend='redis://localhost', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost')

@app.task
def taskThatReturnsArray():
    return ["Mary", "Had", "A", "Little", "Lamb"]

@app.task
def taskThatAddsBrackets(string):
    return "[%s]" % string

@app.task
    def taskThatProcessesItems(item):
        chain = celery.chain(
            taskThatUppercasesString.s(item),
            taskThatAddsBrackets.s()
        )
        return chain()

@app.task
def taskThatUppercasesString(string):
    return string.upper()

@app.task
def dmap(it, callback):
    callback = subtask(callback)
    return celery.group(callback.clone([arg,]) for arg in it)()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chain = celery.chain(
        taskThatReturnsArray.s(),
        dmap.s(taskThatProcessesItems.s())
    )
    res = chain()
```

Comment: If you run the code above, what is the result?

Comment: currently it's not something readable: `['592dbd33-b658-4b1e-ae65-3d68662f2baa', [[['e327aa8f-df4e-4e57-a1e9-735f4e9ddb2b', None], None], [['b6d5e98a-63fc-485c-ab80-f09548117670', None], None], [['bb2105cd-c5e0-4aa4-be85-d88f3e7094db', None], None], [['3fc9af14-bd58-43e1-b036
-ec22757b8275', None], None], [['3297f7b9-6db2-4316-aba7-35ca16daf054', None], None]]]`

Comment: Apparently whatever `celery.group(...)()` returns is not what you want. Did you try to log the data your tasks receive and return?

Comment: Yes, the tasks return correct data, I can see the processed array elements in the Celery worker log file (first they are capitalized in parallel: LAMB, MARY, HAD etc., and them brackets are added, also in parallel). However, the end result is somewhere I don't know, and definitely not in what `res.get()` returns

Comment: Seems what is returned is a serialized-and-then-deserialized `GroupResult` structure (which is deserialized into plain Python objects). Further investigating it right now...